# Angular Material autocomplete not displaying API data until after field change has occurred

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I have two dropdowns on the form.  The static array dropdown(Tasks) shows the complete list when I click in the field. The array of objects from API(Driver Manager) only shows the complete list when I type a letter in that field and backspace.  How do I get the API filtered options dropdown to display when that field is initially selected?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Drivermanager  } from '../../models/drivermanager.model';
import { DrivermanagerService } from '../../services/drivermanager.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-testplatform',
  templateUrl: './testplatform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testplatform.component.scss']
})
export class TestplatformComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  // Statics arrays
  taskOptions = [
    {id:0, name: 'Unassigned'},
    {id:1, name: 'Engineering'},
    {id:2, name: 'Installation'},
    {id:3, name: 'Warehouse'}
  ];

  // Api filled arrays
  drivermanagers: Drivermanager[] = [];
  dmOptions: Drivermanager[] = [];
  filteredDMOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  // Pre-defined arrays
  filteredTaskOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  // Define the FormGroup
  sampleForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  // Form Controls
  taskControl = new FormControl();
  dmControl = new FormControl();


  constructor(public mservice: DrivermanagerService, private fb : FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForm();
    this.getDriverManagers();

    this.filteredTaskOptions = this.taskControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((term) => {
        return this.taskOptions.filter((task) =>
          task.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
        );
      })
    );

    this.filteredDMOptions = this.sampleForm.get('fc_dmanager').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((term) => {
        return this.dmOptions.filter((dm) =>
          dm.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
        );
      })
    );
  }

  initializeForm(){
    this.sampleForm = this.fb.group({
      fc_task: ['', [Validators.required]],
      fc_dmanager: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  displayFn(subject) {
    return subject ? subject.name : undefined;
  }

  getDriverManagers() {
    this.mservice.getDriverManagerList().subscribe((data: Drivermanager[]) => {
      this.drivermanagers = data
      console.log('Fetched Driver Manager List');
      this.drivermanagers.sort((a,b) => {
        let fa = a.name.toLowerCase(),
            fb = b.name.toLowerCase();

        if (fa < fb) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (fa > fb) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      console.log('Sorted dm list - ', this.drivermanagers);
      this.dmOptions = this.drivermanagers;
      console.log('dmOptions - ', this.dmOptions);
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // Do something with that data
  }

  onClear() {
    // Reset the fields on the form
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="container">
    <mat-form-field class="marginright" appearance="outline" [style.width.px]=120 style="font-size: 12px;">
    <mat-label>TASK</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="autotask" formControlName="fc_task" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <mat-autocomplete #autotask="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option [value]="task" *ngFor="let task of filteredTaskOptions | async">
        {{task.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
  <mat-form-field class="marginright" appearance="outline" [style.width.px]=200 style="font-size: 12px;">
    <mat-label>Driver Manager</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="autodm" formControlName="fc_dmanager" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <mat-autocomplete #autodm="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option [value]="dm" *ngFor="let dm of filteredDMOptions | async">
        {{dm.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="button-row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn"  (click)="onClear()">Clear</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a race condition. When your `startWith` is fired, the array you are trying to sort does not yet have a value. You would want to actually attach an observable to it, so that you have the values to sort. You could use `shareReplay` to not trigger that function more than once. So something like this in your component ts:

```
dm$ = this.mservice.getDriverManagerList().pipe(
  shareReplay();
);

ngOnInit() {
  // more code...
    this.filteredDMOptions = this.sampleForm.get('fc_dmanager').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      switchMap((term) => {
        return this.dm$.pipe(
          map((dmOptions) => {
            return dmOptions.filter((dm) =>
              dm.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
            );
          })
        )
      })
    );
}
```

In your template you need to use the `async` pipe to subscribe to the array.

Do the same with your other list.

Here is DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ncaa4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Maybe I missed something but this did not solve the problem.  When I initially click in the Driver Manager input field, there still isn't a dropdown list.

Comment: I attached a Stackblitz demo in the answer, please refer to it. Remember to use `async` pipe in template.

Comment: It didn't work until I changed the variable to not be Observable like what you did in Stackblitz.  I have been at this for weeks but not able to find a viable solution.  If I ever find myself in Finland, I'm buying you a coffee.

Comment: Ha! Yeah, welcome to Finland, it's cold as heck here now :P If you dare come here I will buy you a coffee :P Well, parts of US are cold too, so who knows, maybe you know how it is :) Have a good one and happy coding, glad I could help :)